# Required Permissions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, permissions

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC application that throws a "Required permissions cannot be acquired" exception.
The weird thing is that if I change the location of the folder containing my app to another location, the app runs just fine. (i.e Copy the folder from .../Programs/MyApp to ...Desktop/MyApp)

I have checked the folder permissions and they are fine.

how do i solve this problem?

DG

Comment: Check the Security settings on the IIS application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the error you get when you're eg., requiring FullTrust but are only granted MediumTrust. Since it works when you move folders, my guess is that it's not a machine level config - but a parent application. You can try [forcing full trust in your own web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998341.aspx#paght000020_step1).